# Cannot resolve reference StructField with such signature

Tags: scala, apache-spark, import, signature, bigdata

i've copied a working example of and i've changed it a little, but the core is always the same, but i got always this error in the StructField point:

> cannot resolve reference StructField with such signature

And also gives me this one, inside the signature:

> Type mismatch, expected: Datatype, actual StringType

Here is the part of my code where i got problems:

```
import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData.StringType
import org.apache.spark
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructField
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
     object Test{

      def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

             val file = "/home/ubuntu/spark/MyFile"
                val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Test")
                val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
                val read = sc.textFile(file)
                val header = read.first().toString
                //generate schema from first csv row
                val fields = header.split(";").map(fieldName => StructField(fieldName.trim, StringType, true))
                val schema = StructType(fields)
    }
    }
```

I cannot understand where i'm wrong.
I'm using Spark version 2.0.0

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `GenericData.StringType` is an issue. Use an alias:

```
import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData.{StringType => AvroStringType}
```

or remove this import (you don't use it).